# Two toggle states?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

I have two toggles that are interfering with each other. I am using the [reactstrap modal](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/) and a react accordion component. How do you set two different states?

Right now, when I click on any accordion or on the button for my modal both fire and I open the accordion and show the modal. I am new to React FYI

Part of my component:

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeTab: '1',
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle(tab) {
    if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
      this.setState({
        activeTab: tab
      });
    }
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
  ...
```

Modal Reactstrap Code:

```
<div className="row med-spaces">
    <div className="col-1">
        <p className="event-date">Feb. 28</p>
    </div>
    <div className="col-7">
        <h3 className="no-marg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h3>
        <p className="event-sub no-marg-b">Click the button for modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div className="col-4">
        <a className="event-btn" onClick={this.toggle} href="/"><i></i><span>Submit Order</span></a>
    </div>
</div>

<Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
  <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
  <ModalBody>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </ModalBody>
  <ModalFooter>
    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
    <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
  </ModalFooter>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this

```
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this); //function name is "toggle"
    this.state = {
      activeTab: '1',
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle2 = this.toggle2.bind(this);//function name is "toggle2"
  }

  toggle(tab) { //function name is "toggle"
    if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
      this.setState({
        activeTab: tab
      });
    }
  }

  toggle2() { //function name is "toggle2" , NOW, they are different functions
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }
```

and in the modal call toggle or toggle2 according of what you want, but use one for the modal and other for the accordion. You can't have 2 functions with the same name or ther are gonna overwrite each other